# NativeScript Vue - Firebase Re-login the user on app restart

Tags: firebase, nativescript

I'm using NativeScript-Vue with Firebase authentication which is all working fine.

What I'm trying to do is to route the user directly to the Home component if they are already authenticated with Firebase or if they aren't direct them to the Log In component.

As per my sample code I've passed the onAuthStateChanged parameter when initializing Firebase to check if the user is already authenticated and save the state in isLoggedIn. Then when rendering the Vue instance I check the truthy state of isLoggedIn to determine weather to send them to Home or Log In.

I believe that the Vue instance renders first before the onAuthStateChanged is processed according to my console.

I'll be grateful if someone can provide a pointer.

```
let isLoggedIn = false

firebase.init({

  onAuthStateChanged: data => {
    console.log(data.loggedIn ? "Logged in to firebase" : "Logged out from firebase");
    if (data.loggedIn) {
      isLoggedIn = true
    }
    else {
      isLoggedIn = false
    }
  }
}).then(
    function () {
      console.log("firebase.init done");
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
    }
);

// Prints Vue logs when --env.production is *NOT* set while building
Vue.config.silent = (TNS_ENV === 'production')

new Vue({

  render: h => h('frame', [h(isLoggedIn ? Home : LogIn)])
}).$start()
```

Comment: With Firebase you will have to wait for the internal server call, so it could possibly happen after Vue init. So I would suggest doing this on Home Or may be a seperate loading page, if user token is invalid, take redirect to login.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks for the clarification I'll give it a shot and see if it works.